# Why am I not able to connect my nodejs app to postgres with localhost

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to build a very simple web app using node js and express and I am not using docker since every solution I tried to find revolved around docker, but when I try to connect to postgres database with localhost I get the following error

here is the `DATABASE_URL` : `postgres://postgres:rwandaeric@localhost:5432/focus_server`

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
```

here is the file that I am connecting from `connect.js`

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');
const {config} = require('dotenv');
config();

const pool = new Pool({connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL})
pool.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected');
}); 


const getArticles = (req, res) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM news', (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('found', results);
    res.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getArticles
}
```

`app.js` my server

```
const express =  require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require('./config/connect');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ info: 'Welcome to focus faith family'})
});
app.get('/api/news', db.getArticles);
 app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
})
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your database up and running?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, Yes sir, it is up and running

Comment: Try replacing `localhost` in your `DATABASE_URL` with what you called your Postgres service.

I'm new to docker, but I've found having the database URL use `localhost` it doesn't connect and I get the same error as you. When I use the database service name it does connect. Not sure if this is a docker issue or the `pg` package, or just me.